# Get time in which the app was closed. How?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time

I want to make a idlegame and for that I need to get the time in which the app was closed so I can calculate the income in that offline-time.

My first idea was to get the currentTimeMillis and save them via sharedPreferences and when opening the app again I calculate the difference between the current and the saved time. My problem is the sharedPreferences Variable seems to be 0 all the time.

my Code:

```java
Zeit = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
Zeit_Differenz = Zeit - Zeit_SAVE;

        Log.i("e","aktuelle Zeit: " + Zeit);
        Log.i("e", "gespeicherte Zeit: " + Zeit_SAVE);
        Log.i("e", "errechnete differenz: " + Zeit_Differenz);
```

```java
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putLong("Zeit save", Zeit);
editor.apply();
```

```java
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
Zeit_SAVE = sharedPreferences.getLong("Zeit save", 0);
```

Logcat:

```java
aktuelle Zeit: 1569344292                         (time right now)
gespeicherte Zeit: 0                              (saved time)
errechnete differenz: 1569344292                  (calculated difference)
```

There is other code between these snippets. I just copied the most important code for you.

I hope you can help me, this really is my only idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: You should [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58085235/edit) and show in what parts of the Android lifecycle you are saving and restoring the time value.

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now but I know that im saving in onPause and I restore it with onResume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override methods `Activity.onPause()` and `Activity.onResume()` in order to save the timestamp and then later perform the calculation. That one whitespace in the preference's name `Zeit save` might cause it to always return the default value `0`; better replace that with an `_` underscore, eg. `timestamp_paused`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

I cannot help with the persisting of values to storage, as I do not use Android. But I can show how to record current moment and later calculate elapsed time.

Record current moment.

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> `"2019-09-24T20:50:52.827365Z"`

Parse that string, and capture elapsed time:

```
Duration                                              // Represent a span-of-time not attached to the timeline.
.between(                                             // Calculate time elapsed between a pair of moments.
    Instant.parse( "2019-09-24T20:50:52.827365Z" ) ,  // Parse string in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end means UTC, pronounced “Zulu”. 
    Instant.now()                                     // Capture the current moment in UTC.
)                                                     // Returns a `Duration` object. 
.toMillis()                                           // Interrogates the `Duration` object for its total elapsed time in milliseconds, effectively truncating any microseconds/nanoseconds.
```

## java.time

The modern approach to tracking time uses the *java.time* classes, specifically:

- [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to represent a moment in UTC
- [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) to represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline, basically a count of nanoseconds.

Capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Persist a textual representation of that value using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Read that stored string, and parse as an `Instant`.

```
String input = "2019-09-24T20:50:52.827365Z" ;
Instant then = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Capture the current moment, and calculate elapsed time as a `Duration.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Duration d = Duration.of( then , now ) ;
```

If you want the elapsed time as a total count of milliseconds, interrogate the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object.

```
long milliseconds = d.toMillis() ;  // Total elapsed time in milliseconds, truncating any microseconds/nanoseconds.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).